# Boost mmap performance vs native memory maps

Tags: c++, linux, memory, boost, io

I will be writing a benchmarking tool that will test a mix of IOPS and bandwidth of a disk system and as such I will be turning to file backed memory maps for IO. Because the tool is going to need to be on both POSIX and WinNT platforms I can't just use plain old mmaps. Also from what I understand you have to madvise the Linux kernel that the whole file will be accessed sequentially? Which brings me to Boost memory maps. Are Boost memory maps going to be likely to give me similar performance on similar hardware with similar quality drivers on Windows, Linux and Max OS X? Has anyone benchmarked Boost mmaps across systems?

Comment: Boost memory maps are even faster than native memory maps with hints and everything!  Boost is fantastic.  Everybody should use Boost!  - signed A Random Boost Booster.

Answer (score 0):

I would suspect that there would be no performance difference, because Boost is merely providing a platform agnostic wrapper facility, but I would suggest you test it under your specific circumstances.

Also, Windows NT platforms provide a memory mapping facility -- it's not like memory mapping is a Linux specific feature. For Windows, you'll want `CreateFile`, `CreateFileMapping` and `MapViewOfFile`. The Windows library differs in that creation of the mapping machinery is separate from creating a mapped view. Otherwise the functionality is equivalent. Oh, just like on POSIX, you need to clean up, in this case with `UnmapViewOfFile` on the views and `CloseHandle` on the file mapping and file handle.

Comment: It's worth asking before committing a lot of work to implement both solutions so you can benchmark. A quick answer on SO that boost is just a thin wrapper is worth a lot

Comment: To create multiple address mappings of the same file in POSIX, you just call `mmap()` multiple times with the same file descriptor.

Comment: @Martin: In general yes, but in this case, we're talking about a maybe 4 function calls versus whatever it takes to get boost's setup working. It's not like implementing both solutions is a seriously complicated thing to do. @caf: I didn't explain myself well... I've rewritten that section.

Comment: By that same token a programmer need not ask people how to create an anonymous memory map on on BSD and Linux because if he digs through man pages on both systems long enough he'll know that both support mapping /dev/null. This is a Q&A and people come here to share expertise and listen to others. @Martin: exactly, with the Linux specific readahead behavior that's at least 4 implementations that I need to run on identical hardware to get an idea for my target platforms.

Comment: @Novikov: No, that is completely different. In this case, it has absolutely nothing to do with experience. We have no way of knowing what load you will put on the system. We have no way of knowing what your benchmarking goals are. Do you want to maximize throughput? Minimize access time? Wwe are talking about an OS facility that requires a **maximum** of 3 calls to try. Given that, I think the only answer is to try it yourself, *under loads you would be using*, and see. No amount of experience helps there. OTOH, experience can be helpful when we are dealing with "documetation-type" questions.